# Neptune/Gremlin RemoteConnectionException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I see this issue(exception details posted below) quite frequently while making calls to the Neptune server from AWS Lambda.

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists.
```

Sometimes, I also see a 'Connection reset by peer' exception.

I have setup the Gremlin Java client as follows, following Neptune's best practices document:

```
Cluster
      .build()
      .addContactPoint(NeptuneClusterEndpoint)
      .port(8182)
      .maxContentLength(655360)
      .maxInProcessPerConnection(32)
      .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(32)
      .enableSsl(true)
      .create()
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: TimeoutException on the client is caused due to a wide variety of reasons such as, all connections to the server are busy or some request caused all connections to be closed, hence server is unavailable etc.

1. Can you enable logs in INFO mode and see if you see anything more there?

2. How many queries are you executing in simultaneously? what is the average runtime of each query? what is the configuration for maxwaitforconnection set to on the client?

Comment: Just following up - were you able to get your code working?